# neo4j: Broken pipe error

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to access a database having 0.4 M nodes and 0.9 M parent->child relationship. However, I want to find common parent of two given node using the following query

```
start p=node:nodes(node_id="14697"), h=node:nodes(node_id="25437")
match path=p<-[:PARENT_OF*]-common_ancestor-[:PARENT_OF*]->h
return common_ancestor as most_recent_common_ancestor
order by length(path)
limit 1
```

This query show *Unknown error* in query browser and ***Broken pipe*** error in log. You can check the log from [here](https://gist.github.com/ff9f1b80cc108176f730.git). That message is at line 3266.

I have tried  some simple query like

```
start p=node:nodes(node_id="14697") return p
```

and it works Ok.

Please tell me, what is the problem with the first query and how can I fix that.

Comment: can you try to run it from the neo4j-shell? or at http://localhost:7474/webadmin/#/console/

Comment: same error. Please check the nodes and rels data from here: http://ge.tt/2Gwpvkh1/v/0?c

Comment: your shared file are two csv files.

Comment: Also the shell cannot have the same error.

Comment: Try to limit your paths to start with. e.g. [:PARENT_OF*..5] then increase that number